# Term of the type xxx-troph for a compound not used by an organism

Tags: microbiology, metabolism, terminology

- A prototroph for compound X can make it
- A bradytroph grows faster if X is scavenged
- An auxotroph needs to scavenge X
- A hyperauxotroph lacks both the biosynthetic pathway and the transporters for X

However, I cannot find the term for when the metabolism is rerouted to not need that compound. A term exists and it isn't with an obvious prefix like para, exo, ecto, juxta or similar, but that is as much as I recall: I cannot recall it or where I read it. Has anyone ever encountered said term?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're looking for the word [**mixotroph**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixotroph)?

- A mixotroph is an organism that can use a mix of different sources of energy and carbon.
- In other words, as stated by [Schoonhoven (2010)](http://www.bio.vu.nl/thb/education/Scho2000.pdf):

  > The capability of one organism to be autotrophic and heterotrophic at the
  > same time.

Comment: I was thinking in terms of artificially "biotin-independent" bacteria, where the requirement for biotin is circumvented. However, a different group made it first and they simply used the word independent.                          
Using a different example, E. coli is *ascorbic acid-independent* (GSH acts as vitamin C), it is *auxotrophic for B12* (combalamin), but it is prototrophic for methionine (as it has both routes).